# Disable Google fonts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i just installed "Disable Google Fonts" plugin to inactive em , when i actived it i got those errors 
BTW i'm using wordpress 4

when i tried to active it i got these errors:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'remove_inline_style' not found or invalid function name in /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 505

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php:505) in /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php:505) in /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1173
```

and when i tried to remove the plugin 
i got that error

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'remove_inline_style' not found or invalid function name in /home/ghadaal/public_html/blog/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 505
```

PS here's the plugin [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-google-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

While you are installing a plugin, you need to be careful about plugin test level. That plugin has been tested up to 3.8.3 as below;
[image]

It is not compatible with wp 4.x. In order to delete plugin, go to **/pathto_website/wp-content/plugins/** directory and delete **disable-google-fonts** folder manually. And you can use support section of plugin page to warn author of that plugin in order to make necessary upgrade for that plugin

Comment: i tried to delete it manually and i always get the same error

Comment: Could you please check this query result `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`? and tell me "disable google fonts" exists in the result? You can manually remove name and save again