# how to inactive google font in WordPress without plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website that I want to remove google fonts from it, but there is no resources which how to do that without any plugins.

here is some references that I already search them.
[How to Remove Google Fonts from WordPress (for GDPR / DSGVO)](https://fontsplugin.com/remove-disable-google-fonts/)
[Disable Google fonts in WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25717214/disable-google-fonts-in-wordpress)
and many others, but no one is corresponding with my question.